# How can I know if someone change the default gateway on an XP or 7 client? 

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

I want to keep a track who is changing the default gateway of any Client PC running Windows XP or Windows 7.

Is this in a log anywhere? If not, how can I track or log this event?

Comment: What would they gain by doing this in your network?  Wouldn't it just break their donnection?

Comment: @Zoredache if it's anything like some small networks I've seen, sometimes there's a proxy or filter that is set up and everyone gets this connection, and there's a non-filtered connection used as a gateway also available, so manually changing them lets you choose which to go through. Security and protection through obscurity...

Comment: Well, what about configuring *that* gateway to only allow connections from specific IP addresses? Oh, yeah, that would require someone to actually know what he's doing...

Comment: @Massimo has this right. If you have multiple gateways then these should be restricted on the network level, not by relying on the client to use the correct one.

Comment: Devil's advocate...maybe Param is working at a small office whose network grew "organically" and they're reaching the point where they need to switch from SOHO grade equipment and rethink their management. This type of question seems to arise right around that tipping point...

Comment: @BartSilverstrim Not the case. It's because of a filter/no filter situation. He outlined this in his last question.

Comment: @MDMarra - ah, didn't go through a question history thinking this is a string of events.

Comment: @Dan - no argument there, I was just outlining a scenario where I've seen this happen before. Organic networks seem to grow into this kind of problem until it's time to upgrade from garden to greenhouse and the management is hesitant to go through that kind of cost...so they look for creative solutions within the framework of what they already know.

Comment: @BartSilverstrim How awkward, deleted mine when I saw MDMarra's! But yes, I know what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you do. If you have a small network, you build a small router system, using Linux if you want to do it on the cheap, and put it between your switch for your small network and your network connection. Essentially this becomes your gateway. Then on the router, you tell it that XYZ IP addresses go HERE, and ABC IP addresses go THERE, where HERE is filtered and THERE is not. Filter it by MAC if necessary. Then if they change their IP, they get...nothing. You can't rely on the machines to be properly filtered or set up; users can find a way around it if they have sufficient privileges and time, and they don't particularly like their job environment.

Second, you make sure this is all in your policies...you change the config of the system for non-work related purposes, you're fired. Make sure all employees are aware of this policy.

The Linux router solution (if you have a small network) also allows for filtering and monitoring of websites and such. It's relatively inexpensive. It's flexible. It can give you options for monitoring bandwidth and getting statistics on network use. But it takes some knowledge of how to use Linux and some decent hardware in the network card department so your connection is reliable.

The alternative is to configure your current "allow all" router connection to limit what IP's/machines are allowed to access it, forcing all other traffic through whatever you're using to filter.

Comment: If you want to make it really simple check out ClearOS, its a free SMB gateway, router: http://www.clearfoundation.com

Answer (score 0):

You could write a script which checks the Gateway on computer startup and notifies you if it was changed from the default, or just reset it to the one you want